# Hashing a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, hash

Hey I need to figure out how to turn this string

```
"?q=cat&name=Tim#img=FunnyCat"
```

into the hash

```
({"q" => "cat", "name" => "Tim"})
```

I'm very much stuck on this problem any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using a web framework, then you're asking the wrong question because the framework likely does this for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you strip off the `?` part and trim after `#`, then you get this:

```
require 'cgi'

CGI.parse("q=cat&name=Tim")
# => {"q"=>["cat"], "name"=>["Tim"]}
```

So pre-process with:

```
query = query.sub(/\A\?/, '').sub(/\#.*/, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `URI.parse` and `CGI.parse`. `URI.parse` will help you get the query easily, while `CGI.parse` will do the actual job of parsing the query and transforming it into a hash.

```
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'

CGI.parse(URI.parse('?q=cat&name=Tim#img=FunnyCat').query)
```

this will return `{"q"=>["cat"], "name"=>["Tim"]}`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a library but here's a regex solution anyway:

```
str = "?q=cat&name=Tim#img=FunnyCat"

r1 = /(?<=\?).+?(?=#)/
r2 = /&|=/

str[r1].split(r2).each_slice(2).to_h 
 #=> {"q"=>"cat", "name"=>"Tim"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    [[:alpha:]]+   # match 1 or more letters
    =              # match '='
    [[:alpha:]]+
    (?=&)          # match '&' in positive lookahead
    |              # or
    (?<=&)         # match '&' in positive lookbehind
    [[:alpha:]]+
    =
    [[:alpha:]]+
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = "?q=cat&name=Tim#img=FunnyCat"

str.gsub(r).each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
  k, v = s.split('=')
  h[k] = v
end
  #=> {"q"=>"cat", "name"=>"Tim"}
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that has no block and therefore returns an enumerator. Note that no character substitutions are performed. I've found several situations where it has been helpful to use `gsub` in this way.